# JQuery - Slide div until section end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for some help. I'm new to JQuery and I wrote a script for [My Site](http://lyboards.landyachtztesting.com/skate/test-board/):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$(function() {
    var $spcright  = $(".single-product-content-right"), 
        $spcleft   = $(".single-product-content-left"),
        $spcbottom   = $(".single-product-content-bottom"),
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $spcright.offset(),
        height     = $spcleft.height() - $spcright.height(),
        topPadding = 45;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() < height && $window.width() > 768) {
            console.log(height);
            $spcright.css('position', 'fixed').css('margin-top', '0');
            $spcright.addClass('spc_right');

        } else if($window.scrollTop() >= height && $window.width() > 768) {
            $spcright.css('position', 'absolute').css('margin-top', height+'px');
            $spcright.removeClass('spc_right');

        } else if($window.width() < 768) {
            $spcright.css('position', 'relative').css('margin-top', '0px');
            $spcright.removeClass('spc_right');

        } else {
            $spcright.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });
});
});
```

The purpose is to have the description slide down with the images as you scroll until the end of the div with images (where it would stop). I can't quite seem to get the height nailed.

I tried calling `$(".single-product-content-left").height()`, but that only retreived a value of 200px and not the actual container height (which left me confused). I've been trying other ways, but it doesn't quite seem to work.

TL;DR: Need to retrieve height of left div (`.single-product-content-left`), but I am struggling to do so. Please help.

Edit: HTML for the section

```
    <div class="single-product-content row">
        <div class="single-product-content-left col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="gem-gallery gem-gallery-hover-default"> <div class="ly-gallery-item ly-gallery1" data-image-id="27245">
        <div class="ly-gallery-item-image ly-gallery-item1">
            <img class="27245 img1" src="http://lyboards.landyachtztesting.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="ly-gallery-item ly-gallery2" data-image-id="27244">
        <div class="ly-gallery-item-image ly-gallery-item2">
            <img class="27244 img2" src="http://lyboards.landyachtztesting.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="ly-gallery-item ly-gallery3" data-image-id="27243">
        <div class="ly-gallery-item-image ly-gallery-item3">
            <img class="27243 img3" src="http://lyboards.landyachtztesting.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="ly-gallery-item ly-gallery4" data-image-id="27242">
        <div class="ly-gallery-item-image ly-gallery-item4">
            <img class="27242 img4" src="http://lyboards.landyachtztesting.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
</div>
</div>      </div>

        <div class="single-product-content-right col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <h2 class="product_title" style="color: #111111;">Test Board</h2><p class="price"><span class="woocs_price_code" data-product-id="26570"></span></p>
<div class="product-content entry-content"><p>Do you want to take a board everywhere you go but don&#8217;t want to lug around some giant piece of wood? We&#8217;ve managed to eliminate all the awkward from your life with the tiny Dinghy 24. It&#8217;s compact for quick moves through the streets, letting you dodge those human pylons as they drag their heels on their way to somewhere boring. But not you, you&#8217;re always headed somewhere epic with your Dinghy 24!</p>
<p>The quality and performance are unmatched, we could get into the details, but you&#8217;ll understand better when it&#8217;s under your feet.</p>
<p>24&#8243; Length I 6.5&#8243; Width I 14&#8243; Wheelbase</p>
<p>100% Canadian Maple</p>
</div>

<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="26570" data-product_variations="[]">

            <p class="stock out-of-stock">This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.</p>

    </form>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML?

Comment: Side note; `$(document).ready(function...)` and `$(funciton ...)` are effectively the same thing

Comment: @Taplar: Thanks, I did not know that, will update.

Comment: @Georgiy Sekretaryuk you should paste all relevant code here, rather than encouraging people to visit your/an external website. Right now, your question doesn't have enough context to troubleshoot and answer

Comment: @Mark Added in my edit.

Comment: Have you tried [**.outerHeight()**](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) ?